# Moving to a specific compass bearing using x and y coordinates while keeping velocity constant

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

Givens:

`[x,y] == [East, North]`

`[1, 1] == 1 m/s at 45°` $^1$

`[0, 1] == 0°`

`[1, 0] == 90°`

`[0, -1] == 180°`

etc.

With this in mind, how can I solve for any bearing on a compass while keeping speed constant?

E.g., I want to maintain a speed of 1 m/s, `[1, 1]`, but I want `x` and `y` to represent 180°, not 45°, as they do here.

I've been calculating vectors using:

```
_vector = sqrt((_windSpeedEast^2) + (_windSpeedNorth^2));
```

I've been determining compass bearings using:

```
_bearing = floor ((_windSpeedEast atan2 _windSpeedNorth) + 360 ) % 360;
```

$^1$ - (Using `[1, 1]...` here for the sake of simplicity. In reality, `[0.70711, 0.70711] == 1 m/s` with vector magnitude calculation.)*

Comment: For sake of simplicity, why not say that the velocity vector $[0,1]$ is $1$ m/s at $0^\circ$? No matter what you do you will have to deal with decimals; you've set it up now so that $1$ m/s at $0^\circ$ would be $[0,1.41421]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several other questions similar to this:
[Get vector components from from magnitude and angle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35046/get-vector-components-from-from-magnitude-and-angle)

The way you have set this up, using your own formulas we find that the magnitude (that is, the length) of the vector $[1,1]$ is
$$
\sqrt{\text{_windSpeedEast}^2 + \text{_windSpeedNorth}^2} = \sqrt{1^2 + 1^2}
= \sqrt 2 \approx 1.41421.
$$

In general, in order to get a vector of magnitude $r$ at an angle
$\theta$ clockwise from north in your coordinate system, you need to set
\begin{align}
\text{_windSpeedNorth} &= r \cos \theta,\\
\text{_windSpeedEast} &= r \sin \theta.
\end{align}

The even more general rule (which applies to all Cartesian coordinate systems regardless of which direction is "zero" and regardless of whether your angles go clockwise or counterclockwise) is that $r \cos \theta$ is the component in whichever direction is the "zero" direction, and $r \sin \theta$ is the component in whichever direction is the "positive $90$ degrees" direction.

For your particular example, where you want a vector of magnitude $\sqrt 2$ in direction $180$ degrees (due south), $r = \sqrt 2,$ $\theta = 180^\circ,$
$\cos\theta = -1,$ and $\sin\theta = 0,$ so
\begin{align}
\text{_windSpeedNorth} &= \sqrt 2 \times -1 = -\sqrt2 \approx -1.41421,\\
\text{_windSpeedEast} &= \sqrt 2 \times 0  = 0.
\end{align}
In your notation, you would write this vector as $[0,-1.41421]$.

---

By the way, I noticed you used the term "vector" as if it meant *magnitude,*
and you assign a single numeric value to a variable named `_vector`.
There are one-dimensional vector spaces in which it makes sense to
identify a vector with a single number, but your vectors have two dimensions.
I would have named the variable something like `_magnitude`, since the
value you store there is the magnitude of the vector.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer, and the advice/correction re. the use of vector! I really appreciate it! I now have the function working as intended. Teaching yourself to program sure can be a humbling experience!

Re. the weirdness with wind speed: the base wind speed appears to be baked into the system I'm dealing with. I'm only able to touch it using a few limited API commands, such that the only way to return 1 m/s is when the $x$ and $y$ coordinates are $0.70711$, or thereabouts.